# Mongoose: edit deeply nested (recursively) subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a recursively nested subdocuments (arrays), looks generally like:

```
parent:{
    children:[{
        field,
        children:[{
            field,
            children:[{
                ...
                }]
            },
            {
            field,
            children:[{
                ...
                }]
            },
        ...]
    }
}
```

Meaning every `children` subdocument may have another nested `children` subdocuments.

I'm trying to edit a subdocument (let's call it "child"). For example, I want to edit the child at level 3. This means I need to go down 3 levels of children, access the child and save the document (parent).

What I'm doing now is to send the level to the function, along with the information I want to add to the child. I find the document (`findOne` to the parent's Id), go down the levels, attempt to edit the child, and finally save the document:

```
await parentModel.findOne({'_id': parentId}).populate(/*population needed for the information*/)
  .exec().then(async (result)=>{
    let children = result.children;
    for (let i=0; i<level;i++){
      children = children.children;
    }
    children.push(child); //in my specific case I simply push the child to the children one level above

    await result.save((e,doc)=>{...})
```

What happens is that I do see that `children.push(child)` is successful, but the document does not save it (although the `save` function is successful as well).

I assume it has something to do with the fact that I take `children` locally (`let children...`), but I'm not sure if that's true, so I'm seeking advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you change a nested array you have to "tell" to mongoose that is changed, because by default it not recognize it.

You can do this using markModified('fieldName').

example:

```
parent ---> a mongooose doc
parent.child.push({new child object});
parent.markModified('child);
parent.save();
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know (or find out anywhere) about this. Will I need to apply `markModified` to the specific nested element or would applying to the level 0 children work as well? (i.e., does `markModified` aggregates the "modification" down the nesting?)

Comment: i think that level 0 is enough to tell that all object is change and to resave it

Comment: This still doesn't solve my issue unfortunately. I use `markModified` to the level 0, and I even check `isModified` and it returns `true`. But it still doesn't save the new information properly. Just to make sure it's clear, the difference between my case and your example, I don't change `parent.child` directly, I first set a new object `let thisChild = parent.child` and I push to that object. Perhaps this is the culprit? I'm not sure how deep/shallow the object transference are in js (is `thisChild` a copy or a reference?).

Comment: Obviously I would've changed `parent.child` directly if I could, but because I need to nested-ly get the x-level child I don't see another choice than to make a new object.

Comment: Never mind, I was apparently quite stupid and didn't see that didn't updated an actual field. I did `thisChildren = children.children`, which is non-existent; should've had `thisChildren = children[0].children`. Fixed everything, thanks :)